# Debug Error: Exception is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Tags: java

I have a debug assignment for class that I cannot seem to figure out.  We are told to debug the assignment so that the output for the assignment looks as such.

Output:

```
There is a problem with the Eagle!
Java Result: 9999
```

The code given is as follows:

```
//Superclass for the custom exception.
public class EagleLandingException extends Exception
{
    public EagleLandingException(String msg)
    {
      super(msg);
    }
}
```

and the main class

```
public class ThrowEagleExceptionTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        EagleLanding();
    }
     catch (EagleLandingException badEagle) {
        System.out.printf("%s\n", badEagle.getMessage());
        System.exit(9999);
    }
}
private static void EagleLanding () {
    EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
    System.exit(9999);
}
```

I get an error that "the exception is never thrown" at the line

```
catch (EagleLandingException badEagle)
```

and also receive a "cannot find symbol" error on line

```
EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
```

I don't understand why this is happening and have looked at other questions already posted but can't seem to figure out what the issue is.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
private static void EagleLanding () {
    EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
    System.exit(9999);
}
```

`EagleLandingException(...)` is being interpreted as a call to a method called `EagleLandingException`.  But that is not a method.  It is a constructor, and its name (a class name) is not in the namespace where Java looks for *method* names.  The compilation error is (in effect) saying "I cannot find a **method** called ...".

The other problem is that your `EagleLanding` method is not declared as throwing the exception.  So, when you then try to catch the exception in the caller, the compiler says "this is a checked exception, and since the exception is not declared as thrown, it cannot occur here".  Hence the compilation error.

The correct way to write this is:

```
private static void eagleLanding () throws EagleLandingException {
    throw new EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
}
```

Notes:

1. The `new` causes the exception object to be created
2. The `throw` causes exception to be thrown.
3. The `throws` clause declares that the method throws the checked exception.
4. Statements after the `throw` are unreachable.   If you don't remove them, you will get a compilation error.  (And, besides calling `exit` in a method like that it a bad idea ...)
5. I gave changed the method name to conform with Java style rules.  Methods should start with a lowercase name.

---

In his answer, @javaguy suggests that `EagleLandingException` should be unchecked; i.e. declared as a subtype of `RuntimeException`.

Is this right?  Maybe yes, maybe no.  In the (highly artificial) context that you have given us, it is impossible to know for sure.

However, there are some general guidelines that the Java designers recommend developers should follow:

- Checked exceptions are intended for anticipated events where something may be done about the exception.
- Unchecked exceptions are intended for unanticipated events (e.g. bugs) where (typically) there is not much that a programmer *could* do.

The other criterion people use in deciding whether to use checked or unchecked exceptions is to minimize the amount of boilerplate code; i.e. the `throws` clause.  A lot of people find them annoying, and will go to considerable lengths to avoid them; e.g. by declaring all custom exceptions as unchecked, wrapping standard exceptions in custom exceptions, and so on.

I think that the best path is somewhere in between.  Carefully consider the implications of declaring each exception as checked or unchecked, and use a hierarchy of exceptions to manage the size of `throws` declarations.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful.  I've been having trouble understanding exceptions so this cleared a lot up me.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never throw the exception, you do not even create it. The line `EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");` does nothing, but cause an error. You need to employ the `throw` keyword like this:

```
private static void EagleLanding () throws EagleLandingException {
    throw new EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
}
```

You can also omit `System.exit(9999);`, as it is never reached, because the exception interrupts your program flow an goes straight back into the `catch` branch. The `throws` declaration in the method declaration signals, that you do not handle the exception in the method `EagleLanding`.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
```

to

```
throw new EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
```

Also, since EagleLandingException is a checked one, you'll need to add it to 
EagleLanding () method signature.

```
private static void EagleLanding () throws EagleLandingException {
```

explanation:

you need to create instance of your exception before you can throw it. In java this is done through **new** operator.

The last line in EagleLanding is never executed because an exception is thrown before it and this causes method to exit prematurely. The control then goes into your catch block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line `EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");` which is syntactically incorrect, therefore needs to be changed as below:

```
private static void EagleLanding () throws EagleLandingException{
    //the below statement creates a new EagleLandingException and then hrowing it
    new throw EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
}
```

The main rule with Checked Exception is that either the method has to handle the exception (using `catch` block) or it has to be declared in the method signature using `throws` keyword.

Also, any statements after `throw` statement will NOT be executed (except `finally` block (if any) for the `try`), therefore I removed `System.exit`

The important point that you need to take is that you are actually creating/throwing a checked exception which in general, NOT PREFERRED and is NOT required (unless you have some recovery policy upon throwing/receiving the exception), so my better suggestion is to convert your code using  `RuntimeException` as below:

```
//Extend with RuntimeException instead of Exception
public class EagleLandingException extends RuntimeException
{
    public EagleLandingException(String msg)
    {
      super(msg);
    }
}

public class ThrowEagleExceptionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            EagleLanding();
        }
        catch (EagleLandingException badEagle) {
            System.out.printf("%s\n", badEagle.getMessage());
            System.exit(9999);
        }
    }

    //now you don't need to declare the EagleLandingException
    private static void EagleLanding () {
        throw new EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
    }
```